# USB device driver module getting killed while executing insmod?

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, linux-kernel

While running `make`, it is showing no warnings or errors, but when I am inserting the basic USB device driver module inside the running kernel, then I am getting a "killed" message.

**Here is my code:**

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/usb.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

#ifndef DEBUG
#define DEBUG
#endif

static struct usb_driver skel_driver = {

};

static void __exit usb_deregister_func(void)
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
        printk(KERN_INFO "Begin : %s",__func__);
        #endif

    usb_deregister(&skel_driver);

    #ifdef DEBUG
        printk(KERN_INFO "End : %s",__func__);
        #endif  
}

static int __init usb_register_func(void)
{
    int ret_val;

    ret_val = 0;    

    #ifdef DEBUG
    printk(KERN_INFO "Begin : %s",__func__);
    #endif

    ret_val = usb_register(&skel_driver);
    if(ret_val)
    {
        #ifdef DEBUG
        printk(KERN_ERR "ERROR : usb_register().");
        #endif

        return -1;
    }

    #ifdef DEBUG
    printk(KERN_INFO "End : %s",__func__);
    #endif

    return 0;
}
module_exit(usb_deregister_func);
module_init(usb_register_func);
```

Comment: Did you check `dmesg`, `/var/log/syslog`, `var/log/messages` for any information?

Comment: yaa,  I checked var/log/messages file it is saying unable to handle NULL pointer dereference.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation "Writing a USB driver", you need to define at least 5 parameters in the [usb_driver structure](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-13-sect-4):

```
static struct usb_driver skel_driver = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .name = "skeleton",
    .id_table = skel_table,
    .probe = skel_probe,
    .disconnect = skel_disconnect,
};
```

The register action is probably trying to read one of these fields.